# View object with used texture

Tags: texturing, materials, optimization

I'm working on a project with a lot of objects, I want to make the file a lot smaller, because its overloading my hardware.

I want to see which objects are using the selected texture. I'm in the shader editor, and I don't know how to look in my scene, and I have made a mess of the scene and materials.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot or .blend file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a Viewport color to your material.
That way, all objects with the same material will have one distinct color in *Solid view*.

[image]